# Discount attribute is not visible in attributes set

Tags: attributes, discount, attribute-set, attribute-group

I am new to Magento 2 and I am wondering why `discount` attribute is not visible in the `store -> Attribute set -> Default -> Groups`.
I checked that the `discount` attribute is present in the Database.

What can I do? How can I show it also on the frontend?

I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks

[image]

Admin  attribute sets

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Might be you have not assign your `discount` attribute to the `Groups`

Go to the `Store -> Attribute set -> Default` and find `discount` attribute from  `Unassigned Attributes` list and assign to the `Groups` and save `Attribute Set`

Run the command `php bin/magento cache:flush` and check.

Hope it help.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I am not able to find the discount attribute neither in Unassigned attributes and nor in assigned.

Comment: which database table are you showing attribute ?

Comment: eav_attributues i think...  First I tried to create a discount attribute because it was not showing anywhere in admin and not even in frontend. When I created it shows me an error message that the discount attribute already exists in the admin. So later, I checked the database tables and the discount attribute was in a table but I don't remember the name of the table exactly. I think it was attributes_eav or catalog_eav.. but I will tell you later, I am out right now.

Comment: can you please check the question again? I updated with images now.